# aws iot - mosquitto_sub does not subscribe

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto, aws

This is my policy document:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Connect",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:iot:us-east-2:000000000000:client/sub",
        "arn:aws:iot:us-east-2:000000000000:client/pub"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Subscribe",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:us-east-2:000000000000:topicfilter/org/cid/+/data"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Publish",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:us-east-2:000000000000:topic/org/cid/sample/data"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Receive",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:us-east-2:000000000000:topic/org/cid/sample/data"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is my publishing client:

```
mosquitto_pub -h endpoint-ats.iot.us-east-2.amazonaws.com -p 8883 -i pub --cafile aws-iot-root-ca-1.pem --cert pub-certificate.pem.crt --key pub-private.pem.key -t /org/cid/sample/data -m 'Hello'
```

And, this is my subscribing client:

```
mosquitto_sub -h endpoint-ats.iot.us-east-2.amazonaws.com -p 8883 -i sub --cafile aws-iot-root-ca-1.pem --cert sub-certificate.pem.crt --key sub-private.pem.key -t /org/cid/+/data  -d
```

The subscription never goes through; it keeps reconnecting.

```
Client sub sending CONNECT
Client sub received CONNACK
Client sub sending SUBSCRIBE (Mid: 1, Topic: /org/cid/+/data, QoS: 0)
Client sub sending CONNECT
```

The certificate is attached to the policy correctly.

Is there an option to define publish/subscribe settings per client identifier? What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things:

1. The `+` as a wild card for subscription is **NOT** honored. From the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/pub-sub-policy.html):

> The MQTT wildcard character '+' is not treated as a wildcard within a
>   policy. Attempts to subscribe to topic filters that match the pattern
>   foo/+/bar like foo/baz/bar or foo/goo/bar fails and causes the client
>   to disconnect.

2. The topic string shouldn't have the leading the leading slash.

Therefore, I changed the policy to have the exact topic string and in my pub and sub clients removed the leading slash. It works now.

:roll-eyes: